# GWT @UiHandler dont work

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I'm using GWT UiBinder... but I cant use @UiHandler because it not work.

xml

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

        <g:Button ui:field="btn" text="btn"></g:Button>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Java

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class HowToHelp extends Composite {

    interface HowToHelpUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, HowToHelp> {
    }

    private static HowToHelpUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(HowToHelpUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    Button btn;

    public HowToHelp() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiHandler("btn")
    void handleClick(ClickEvent e) {
        Window.alert("Hello, AJAX");
    }

}
```

the **Window.alert("Hello, AJAX");** never is called. I did exactly what was passed on the official GWT: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

There is a complect project with some error [zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1b7Ztpt0C_0aW0wU1RXT0lNNlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Code looks OK. Are you sure there's nothing wrong with the project? Maybe you didn't save your changes before refreshing the application? Have you tried cleaning the project, etc.? Are there any errors/exceptions in DevMode or browser's console?

Comment: I second Igor, the presented code is not the issue. You see the button in the page, if you use super dev mode, the sdm server started as expected? did you recompile with sdm?

Comment: No errors, no exeptions only dont work. I'm using super dev, and see the button normaly

Comment: What if you build your application to JavaScript and run it "normally", without SDM or DevMode?

Comment: I'm stumped. Can you upload your whole project? (or example, a zip archive on Dropbox) So that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: my [Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1b7Ztpt0C_0aW0wU1RXT0lNNlk/view?usp=sharing) is here, I'ts another project with some problem

Comment: Are you able to launch and run the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked zip, code missing from the question:

```
package source.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class UiHandlerTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.getBodyElement().appendChild(new TheHandlerTest("My Button").getElement());

    }

}
```

The problem is that you are adding a widget to another widget without actually doing the *add* part of it ;). Instead, you are *appending the contents* of the uibinder-widget *to the contents* of the RootPanel widget.

Instead, do this (it is shorter/simpler, and won't have this bug):

```
RootPanel.get().add(new TheHandlerTest("My Button"));
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, it really makes sense

Comment: Glad to hear it - make sure to post all the code next time ;).